# Как получить сообщение с кубиком от пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу игрового бота "dice", бот отправляет кубик

```
bot_data = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    bot_data = bot_data['dice']['value']
    print(bot_data)
```

Далее очередь пользователя отправлять кубик

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Теперь ваша очередь")
await Dice.get.set()
```

Как получить сообщение с кубиком от пользователя?
Нужно хранить значение кубика, в переменной user_data

```
if bot_data > user_data:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы проиграли")
elif bot_data < user_data:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Вы выиграли")
else:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ничья")
```

Comment: Подскажите, прежде чем задать вопрос вы глянули документацию?)

Comment: Целый час просматривал документацию, не смог найти, то что нужно. Либо плохо переводил ее

Comment: Почему я вижу в описании [функции](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_dice.html#aiogram.methods.send_dice.SendDice) что именно она [вернет](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message) и там есть одноименное поле ```dice``` содержащее такую [структуру](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/dice.html#aiogram.types.dice.Dice), заняло ровно 2 минуты, комментарий дольше форматировал...